# Edit contents of NSMutableArray who's name is stored in contents of NSString

Tags: ios, arrays, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a function that accepts NSString variable in parameters and appends Array at the end which gives it the name of array already defined in class.
How can i edit that array ?

```
-(void) editArray:(NSString*)str{ //suppose str value is first 

NSString* myArrayName = [str stringByAppendingString:@"Array"]; //firstArray
```

myArrayName contains the name of NSMutableArray already defined in class.. How can i access this array and edit it's values ?

```
NSMutableArray *myArray=[self valueForKey:myArrayName]; //suppose myArrayName is equal to @"firstArray"
```

The above technique is not working as it copies the contents of firstArray to myArray and if i change contents of myArray it doesn't effect firstArray

Comment: This is a poor design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one nsarray *array alloc it and add your values in it.
Then add the values by method `addValuesFromArray` from array in your reference array.

Don't allocate your reference array as it will lose previous reference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are wrong. If your class instance has property(or iVar) of `NSMutableArray` (as you called it 'firstArray'), and it's instantiated, when you calls

```
NSMutableArray *myArray=[self valueForKey:myArrayName];
```

**myArray** and your defined variable **firstArray** will reference to the **same** NSMutableArray object.
So if after that you change contents of myArray (for example [myArray removeLastObject]), myArray and firstArray will still reference to same array object (which will now contain objectsCount-1.)

Hence, mistake can be if you assign to myArray another object and expect that firstArray will also reference to this object:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray=[self valueForKey:myArrayName]; //firstArray and myArray becomes equal
myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anotherArray]; //firstArray and myArray not equal anymore!
```

Comment: myArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"AUSTRALIA",@"ENGLAND",@"NEW ZEALAND",@"WEST INDIES",@"ZIMBABWE"]];

Comment: Then how should i enter these values in myArray so that they are also stored in firstArray ?

Comment: assign it back to firstArray `[self setValue:myArray forKey: myArrayName];`, but this is unreliable solution which can lead to another mistakes in future, better try to avoid it.